# Is it possible to fire 2 receive callback which is fired by 1 send?

Tags: c++, c, networking, tcp, io

I'm working on a networking project. I have to know, if I send a data from a client to server listener, can listener handle this data with 2 or more callbacks (TCP-blocking)? Namely I've sent "Hello World", can server listener (TCP-blocking) handle this receive like 1"Hello" 2"World" or 1"Hell" 2"o World" etc.? If this is posibble I'm going to create a packet handler for my TCP data packets. Thanks!

**EDIT:** *(more desciption)*, Is this posibble (TCP-blocking)?

- Client says "Hello world"
- Server reads "Hello" in first callback **"recv();"** (***recv();*** function gives "Hello" output)
- Server reads " world" in second callback **"recv();"** (***recv();*** function gives " world" output)

Comment: It is definitely possible, fragmentation is in the hands of the underlying network.

Comment: for fragmentation, you can do this, you can even have more than 2 splitting. That depends on the tcp ip stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is absolutely possible. In this particular case, it's quite unlikely, but if your packet is a bit larger than 12 bytes - say several hundred or a few thousand bytes, it will almost certainly get split up if you send it somewhere further than your local network.

It should be noted that you can also get the opposite problem - the sending side sends two individual "packets", and the receiving side receives only one lump of data. Bear in mind that TCP is a stream protocol, not a packet protocol - packets only exist as part of the underlying protocol stack, and they can be split and merged as the network sees fit. All that you are guaranteed is that the data you receive is in the correct order, and that the checksum for the lump of data was correct.

Comment: That means I have to create my own packet handler system. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you know exactly how long each part of data is (for e.g. "Hello" is 5 characters long), you can block on reading in first callback and then on second (with separate calls to recv()).

Or if you know how these parts will be separated (in your case it's space), then you can recv() in first callback by 1 byte and then, when you receive your separator, switch to receive in second callback.

Or maybe you can differentiate them using your special protocol (if you have one).

But still, I'm not sure in which layer do you want these packages to be interpreted separately.